# How to handle adding/removing views in LinearLayout on Android

Tags: android, dynamic, scrollview, android-linearlayout, nested

I have one of those screens where you fill user info, some other EditTexts etc. and send it to server. But there is section something like add note (just example). User can add as many notes as he want. At the beginning there is just button add note. When user press it then new TextView spawns above and he can fill it, or remove it. Then he can touch add note again and whole process repeats. You sure know what I mean. At the end I take all filed notes and send it to server.

I know that the way to do it is - on btn press inflate my TextView + delete btn layout and add it to linear layout. On btnPress then get its parent or whatever and remove it from layout.

However this is pretty annoying thing to do as it requires inflating, children views managing and all the other stuff. What I am asking is - is there some other way to do that? Maybe some library, or possibility to set adapter to linear layout etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could consider using a ListView.

Comment: I can't because there is a lot of another views in this screen, therefore I need to use ScrollView. Adding notes is like 1 of 8 fields to be filled.